# How to return the sum of all the dynamic TextInput fields in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      InputArr: [],
      FinalVal: [],
      Sum: 0,
    };
  }

  AddNewView = () => {
    this.setState({
      InputArr: [
        ...this.state.InputArr,
        <TextInput
          style={styles.FieldNew}
          keyboardType="numeric"
          onChangeText={(e) =>
            this.setState({ FinalVal: this.state.FinalVal.concat(e) })
          }
        />,
      ],
    });
  };

  CalBtnFunc = () => {
    var Total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.state.FinalVal.length; i++) {
      Total += Number(this.state.FinalVal[i]);
    }
    this.setState({ Sum: Total });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.AddBtn} onPress={this.AddNewView}>
          <Text>Click to add new Field</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.AddBtn} onPress={this.CalBtnFunc}>
          <Text>Calculate</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View>{this.state.InputArr}</View>

        <Text>Sum is : {this.state.Sum}</Text>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },

  AddBtn: {
    marginTop: 30,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },

  FieldNew: {
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

export default App;
```

I'm trying to make a program where the user can add TextInput fields dynamically and once the user clicks on calculating it should return the sum of all the values in all the TextInput fields.

*TextInput will only accept numeric values.

I have written the code but it's not working as I want it to be.

What I have done:

when **click to add new field** is clicked it appends a TextInput field to the state variable called **InputArr**(Array) and all the values of the TextInput field are stored in a state variable called **FinalVal**. On clicking the **calculate** button I have used a for loop to iterate over all the values present in the **FinalVal** array and sum it and store it in another state variable called **Sum**.

Here's the Code Link (Snack) : [Click to view code](https://snack.expo.dev/Du9nSkgMN)

Comment: You are using spread operator when you add a new TextInput but why use concat for text value? why not spread operator again? :)

Comment: Please [edit] this question to include your code here rather than linking to it externally.  Code linked externally may not be at that link permanently, and may not be licensed such that it can be used in answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed AddNewView and CalBtnFunc to make it work.
Let's get through the changes I've made:

```
const CustomTextInput = ({name, _onChange}) => (
  <TextInput
    style={styles.FieldNew}
    keyboardType="numeric"
    onChangeText={(value) => {
      _onChange(value, name)
    }}
  />
);
```

1. Made a custom Component "CustomTextInput" to pass through it a name to be able to differentiate the different inputs that get added dynamically and a custom onChange function (_onChange).

AddNewView becomes:

```
AddNewView = () => {
    this.setState({
      InputArr: [
        ...this.state.InputArr,
        <CustomTextInput
          name={this.state.InputArr.length + 1}
          _onChange={(value, name) => {
            this.HandleChange(value, name)
          }}
        />,
      ],
    });
  };
```

```
HandleChange = (value, name) => {
    const newFinalVal = {...this.state.FinalVal};
    newFinalVal[`${name}`] = value

    if (!isNaN(value)) this.setState({ FinalVal: newFinalVal})
 }
```

2. Inside the function that handles the change instead of having FinalVal as an array, I made it an object to store individually the value of each input. The object FinalVal will look something like this {"1": 10, "2": 7, ....}

```
  CalBtnFunc = () => {
    var Total = 0;
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state.FinalVal)) {
      Total += Number(value);
    }
    this.setState({ Sum: Total });
  };
```

3. Now since we have an array instead of an object, I changed CalBtnFunc to loop through it with for (const of) syntax instead of a normal loop.

Here's a working snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@whygee/grounded-bagel